# how could I use array in push operator on aggregation function, I got exception: aggregating group operators are unary ($push) error

Tags: mongodb

I want to find all the patients who has got `cough` and `headache` in his/her all medical records

Every medical record contains two fields to record symptom, "`SYMPTOM_1`, `SYMPTOM_2`"

I queried by the follwoing query , but I got this error.

`exception: aggregating group operators are unary ($push)`

I expect to find the patients got cough and headache in his medical records history

#### And the expected results should be **Mary** and **Jack**

codes for cough : `cough_codes = ["477  ","4770 "]`
codes for headache : `headache_codes = ["147  ","1470 "]`

## Here my query

```
cur= db_conn.medical_records.aggregate(
        [
            {"$match":{
                 "$and":[
                   {
                    "$or":[
                        {'SYMPTOM_1': '477  '},
                        {'SYMPTOM_2': '4770 '}
                      ]
                   },
                   {
                    "$or":[
                        {'SYMPTOM_1': '147  '},
                        {'SYMPTOM_2': '1470 '}
                      ]
                   },                   
                 ]
               }
            },        
            { "$sort": { "APPL_DATE": 1}},
            { "$group": 
                  {
                      "_id": "$ID", 
                      "dis": { "$push": ["$SYMPTOM_1","$SYMPTOM_2"] }
                  }
            }
        ]
    ) # end of aggregate query
```

## Medical records

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mary",
    "SYMPTOM_1": "4770  ",
    "SYMPTOM_2": "477  ",
    "datetime": "2011-04-02"
},

{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jack",
    "SYMPTOM_1": "477  ",
    "SYMPTOM_2": "4770  ",
    "datetime": "2011-04-02"
},

{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Mark",
    "SYMPTOM_1": "477  ",
    "SYMPTOM_2": "4770  ",
    "datetime": "2010-01-02"
},

....


{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Jack",
    "SYMPTOM_1": "477  ",
    "SYMPTOM_2": "1470  ",    
    "datetime": "2015-04-09"
},

{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Mary",
    "SYMPTOM_1": "477  ",
    "SYMPTOM_2": "147  ",    
    "datetime": "2010-09-02"
}
```

Comment: try with this "dis": { "$push": { SYMPTOM_1: "$SYMPTOM_1", SYMPTOM_2: "$SYMPTOM_2" }},

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify "_id" while grouping data in mongo query.

As per sample data provided, you can try out following :

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {"$match":{
             "$and":[
               {
                "$or":[
                    {'SYMPTOM_1': '477'},
                    {'SYMPTOM_2': '4770'}
                  ]
               },
               {
                "$or":[
                    {'SYMPTOM_1': '147'},
                    {'SYMPTOM_2': '1470'}
                  ]
               },                   
             ]
           }
        },        
        { "$sort": { "APPL_DATE": 1}},
        { "$group": 
              {
                  "_id": "$_id", 
                  "dis": {  "$push": { SYMPTOM_1: "$SYMPTOM_1", SYMPTOM_2: "$SYMPTOM_2" }}
              }
        }
    ]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Accumulators:

```
    Accumulators.push("dis", 
                    new BasicDBObject("SYMPTOM_1", "$SYMPTOM_1")
                        .append("SYMPTOM_2", "$SYMPTOM_2"))
```